# Copy Folder from one storage account to other in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I have Container A, inside which there is a directory B. Inside B, there are some folders. I want to copy all folders directly to another storage account with the help of copy activity. I have tried "Preserve Hierachy" in Sink copy behaviour but didn't work at all. Also I want to confirm in source and sink dataset filepath should be till folder B or need to specify folder names as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to achieve your requirement.

As you are dealing with copying folders, there might be different types files involved. So, use Binary datasets as source and sink in copy activity.

**My Source:**

[image]

In Source dataset, give the file path till the container.

[image]

In the copy activity, use wild card path and give the path till the folder name. Make sure you check on recursive in this.

[image]

In the sink dataset, give the file path till the folder.

[image]

Select Preserve hierarchy in the copy activity sink.

[image]

Now, execute the pipeline and your files with same structure will be copied to the target location.

[image]

Comment: What if I have another folder C inside B, and I have folders data inside C then what should be the paths and dataset paths?

Comment: whatever folders and files you have in folder B, all those will be copied to the target with the above approach.

Comment: I want to copy folders inside C incase, then I need to update path in wildcard path? also I tried above approach and it is not working

Comment: Yes, if you want to copy the files in C, you need to add the path till C in the wild card path `B/C`. what files are you getting? Did you checked recursive in copy activity source?

Comment: yes I have check recursive in copy activity. Nothing has been copied after successful debug

Comment: Can you share your pipeline JSON? also provide your source and sink dataset configurations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255759/discussion-between-akhil-omar-and-rakesh-govindula).